# QObject from C++ to QML to QML to C++ (in a list)

Tags: c++, qml

My idea is to have a bunch of instances of a QObject drived class in a list (created in C++). This list is then passed to QML and each entry can be viewd by a separate QML Object. Now I want to be able to pass a specific instance back to C++ (e.g. when clicked).

Here is some code:

QObject derived class

```
class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name NOTIFY nameChanged)

    Data(std::string n):_name(n){};
    QString name(){return QString::fromStdString(_name);};
signals:
    void nameChanged();
private:
    std::string _name;
}
```

Controller (creating list and receiving selected instance)

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Data> list READ list NOTIFY listChanged)

    Controller()
    {
        _list.append(new Data("data 1");
        _list.append(new Data("data 2");
        _list.append(new Data("data 3");
    };
    QQmlListProperty<Data> list() //  <--- provide data to QML
    {
        return QQmlListProperty<Grammar>(this, _list);
    };
    void takeThisOne(Data* d)// <--- receive selected instance from QML
    {
        //do something with d
    }
signals:
    void listChanged();
private:
    QList<Data*> _list;
}
```

QML main (displaying Data list)

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    id: mainWindowContainer
    width: 800
    height: 500

    ListView
    {
        id: dataList
        delegate: Rectangle{
                  height: 10
                 width: 100
                   Text{text: name}
                  }
        model: controller.list // <-- what data type are the list items here?
    }

    Button
    {
        id: btnOpen
        text: "open selected Data in the DataViewer"
        onClicked{ 
          // what data type is dataList.currentItem and dataList.currentItem.modelData?
          var dataViewer = Qt.createComponent("DataViewer.qml").createObject(mainWindowContainer, {data: dataList.currentItem.modelData});
            dataViewer.show()}
    }
}
```

QML DataViewer (displaying data and returning it to the controller)

```
Window
{
    height: 400
    width: 800
    property variant data // <--- tried 'property Data data', but did not work

    TextArea
    {
       text: data.name
    }

    Button
    {
       id: btnReturn
       text: "return to controller"
       onClicked: {controller.takeThisOne(data)} //  <--- does not work
    }
}
```

I hope this example code is understandable. Thanks for helping!

EDIT:

I'm doing `qmlRegisterType<Data>()` in the main. Also tried `qmlRegisterType<Data>("stuff", 1, 0, "Data")` and importing `stuff 1.0` into DataViewer.
The problem is, that I don't know which data type my Data is at different points:

```
Controller: list of Data*
QML main  : list of ???
            dataList.currentItem = ???
            dataList.currentItem.modelData = ???
DataViewer: variant or Data (according to property type, but Data does not work)
Controller: obviously not Data* as hoped, but what else?
```

Comment: Did you register the `Data` type for QML? ie `qmlRegisterType<Data>();` in your main().

Comment: Yes, I did. I added a little more detail to the question

Comment: Try passing `{data: dataList.currentItem}` instead of `dataList.currentItem.modelData` to DataViewer. And `dataList.currentIndex` must be set first to get `currentItem`.

Comment: I already tried this as well. While I could access the data's name property from DataViewer with "data.modelData.name", returning the data from the DataViewer to the Controller with controller.takeThisOne(data) still doesn't work. What data type schould dataList.currentItem be anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this! The trick is to use

`{data: dataList.model[dataList.currentIndex]}`

instead of `{data: dataList.currentItem]}` or `{data: dataList.currentItem.modelData]}` in the main.qml. Though I still don't know what data types are used and why currentItem seems to use a different data type than model[dataList.currentIndex], this works perfectly!